# Full background image

Tags: html, css, background

I use background-size:cover so that the background positioning area is completely covered by the background image. But setting it "cover" cuts my background image. Is there any other way to use "cover" without cutting the image ?

the html :

```
<body>
<img src="https://codecademy-content.s3.amazonaws.com/courses/web-beginner-en-3pc6w/images/avatar.jpg" height="250" width="250">
<p>Hi! I am learning how to make
my very own web page! I really like
blueberry muffins and long walks on
the beach.</p>
<input type="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="submit" href="#">
</body>
```

the css :

```
body {
    text-align:center;
    background:url("http://121clicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bokeh_photography_03.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
p {
    font-size: 24px;    
}
input {
  border: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  background: limegreen;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it 'cuts' your image? You mean that the bottom of the image is cut off? Because the only other option would to make the page scrollable or stretch the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this

```
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
    background:url("http://121clicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bokeh_photography_03.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/23RDa/)

Answer (score 1):

There's three values of `background-size` that might be relevant:

- `cover` (you're using this one) — tries to make the image cover the screen, even if it cuts it off
- `contain` — tries to make the image as big as possible without cutting it off
- `100% 100%` — stretches the image to fit exactly, distorting its aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but it might stretch the image a bit:

```
<body>
    <img src="https://codecademy-content.s3.amazonaws.com/courses/web-beginner-en-3pc6w/images/avatar.jpg" height="250" width="250">
    <p>Hi! I am learning how to make
```

my very own web page! I really like
blueberry muffins and long walks on
the beach.

With css like this:

```
body {
    text-align:center;
    background:url("http://121clicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bokeh_photography_03.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
p {
    font-size: 24px;    
}
input {
    border: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    background: limegreen;
    color: black;
}
```

Like I said, it might stretch the image a bit but... :/

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cR6XR/).

Comment: I've tried your code but it really stretched the background-image. Thanks though!